# Type a special character with a regular keyboard

Tags: apple-id, setup

I am trying to reinstall an iMac but I don't have the original Apple keyboard. Instead a  "regular" keyboard is attached.
I can't find out how to type the "at" symbol (@). I need it to enter my Apple ID so I can download Mavericks to reinstall the sytem.

Is there any way to type it or circumvent the Apple ID login?

Comment: What does this "regular" keyboard look like? Is the @ symbol on shift-2?  What happens if you just type shift-2?

Comment: Shift-2 just showed '2' but your response got me thinking. It is a Logitech K120 (Belgian, AZERTY), so I changed the input language to USA, where shift-2 gives an @ indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by temporary switching the input language back to USA, type shift-2 and then change it back to Belgian to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Either look at the keyboard viewer:

[image]
[image]

Or google for pictures of Apple keyboards:

[image]

Comment: He has a Logitech Belgian azerty keyboard, which has @ at a different place than the picture of the Apple keyboard you have provided.